# json form api url in angular js

Tags: angular, http, httprequest, angular-http

**I am trying to load .json file which have some setting dat**a

**server.js code**

```
(function () {
app.factory("configService", ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        getResponders: function () {
            var url = 'https://example.com/assets/js/service/config.json',
            apiHeaders = {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
            };

            return $http({
                   method: "GET",
                   url: url,
                   headers: apiHeaders,
                   data: {}
            }).then(function (res) {
                console.log('response : ' + res);
            }, function (res) {
                console.log('error : '+res);
            });

        }
    };
}]);
```

})();

**and tying to get res but it show error:**

*Failed to load https://example.com/assets/js/service/config.json: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8678' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All HTTP calls that you make in Angular are making AJAX calls in the background. As such it respects all the [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) rules.

The called script needs to allow you access. If it doesn't do that you can't force it.